# How to display user's movement in real time in Android MapBox SDK

Tags: android, sdk, maps, mapbox, mapbox-android

How to make MapBox SDK(Android) so that when the user moves around the map, a line is drawn behind him in real time (his movement itself)

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-location-listening/ shows how to track a user's location.

Every time a new `Location` arrives in `onSuccess()`, you'll:

1. create [a `Point`](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/overview/geojson/#geometries) (`Point point = Point.fromLngLat(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE);`) with the `Location` object's coordinates.
2. Add the `Point` to a list of `Point`s to create a `LineString`.

   LineString lineString = LineString.fromLngLats(pointList);
3. Use the `LineString` to update the `LineLayer`'s geojson with the new `LineString` (see the second code snippet box in https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/overview/geojson/#geojson-updates.

All of this is basically a combination of https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-location-listening and https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/moving-icon-with-trailing-line (without the animation or `PointEvaluator` stuff from the second example, because you don't need it to move the device location puck).

Comment: Hi! I am struggling for adding a simple line... using the new version 10.6. Would you have any hint regarding the question I just posted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72930297/draw-in-real-time-a-line-that-corresponds-to-the-users-route-using-mapbox-and-a